# OpenSSL interface with a specific PKCS11 engine binary

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11, hsm

I have a PKCS11 library from a HSM and I would like to use the OpenSSL to interface with the PKCS11 library to generate keys and certificates.

How do I do that without needing to install external third party software other than the HSM, PKCS11 binary provided by the HSM and the OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly your library includes, how it's compiled, and how compliant it is with OpenSSL, I believe you just need to use the `openssl engine` command, although I've never used it before to add an engine.

This seems like a pretty good source of information.  It talks about some third-party software, but I think that's just for testing/troubleshooting (unless you consider EVP, an OpenSSL API, third-party software).  Starting on page 26, it seems to have some comprehensive documentation on how to add the PKCS11 engine to OpenSSL.

http://www.dnssec.cz/files/nic/doc/hsm.pdf

Comment: I believe OpenSC, which provides tools and libraries to work with smart cards, provides a OpenSSL compatible PKCS11 engine but it's meant to interface with OpenSC compatible smart cards or at least smart cards that support open standards access protocols, like CCID for USB connected smart cards. You would think there should be some standardisation in the world of cryptography and HSMs but even by googling around, you'll find out that it's a real mess. Anyway, you'd need to test first. Check out [OpenSC's PKCS11 engine for OpenSSL](https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11).